# How can i do to detect when player enters in fullscreen mode?

Tags: events, fullscreen, mediaelement.js

There are an event to be detected when player enters in fullscreen mode?

Detail: Flash fallback is present

Comment: Are you using Flowplayer or some other library, or starting from scratch?

Comment: I'm using mediaelement.js ( http://mediaelementjs.com ).

Answer (score 0):

Place this function in your event listener: `console.log(player.isFullScreen);`
This will print true if player is in fullscreen mode.
In order to successfully print the content of the variable you need to create the player
dynamically and assign it to a variable called player.